# split NSString into NSArray in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

i'm trying to split NSString to NSArray.String like this:

```
@"text,image".
```

And I am splitting it like this:

```
arrayAnsType = [self.strAnsType componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"Terms array %@",arrayAnsType);
```

But output like this:

```
(
    "(\n    \"text",
    "image\"\n)"
)
```

Comment: Change the log to first print the string and then the array. Also, you didn't actually ask a question...

Comment: the provided text would not result in that array. give us a correct example.

Comment: @Wain i already did this...

Comment: @vikingosegundo ,self.strAnsType=@"text,image"....

Comment: @Faridullah: this would end up in `( "text", "image")`, but your string contains `"` and whitespace characters. Give us the real string.

Comment: @Wain i actually asking about output,why the including these things.. \n\

Comment: I agree with @vikingosegundo the example you give does not make sense and should be impossible

Comment: Edit your question, show us exactly how is generated strAnsType.

Comment: @vikingosegundo you are rights....thanx alot..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print array you will see output as below... this is the way array look like on console.
(
    text,
    image
)

You can try accessing array object as below

```
NSLog("@%@", arrayAnsType[0]);
```

This will print     "text"